# Fontspec can't find fonts included in tex live 2018

Tags: fonts, texlive, fontspec, libertinus

This `MWE` works in tex live versions prior to the 2018 version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec, lipsum}
    \setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

In tex live 2018, compiling this results in the error

```
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Libertinus Serif" cannot be found.
```

I've checked, and the Libertinus Serif font is included in the folder `texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertinus`, just as it was in tex live 2017. Since this no longer compiles, I assume `fontspec` or `xelatex` has made some recent changes with respect to how it loads fonts?

EDIT:

I've installed tex live 2018 as a portable version in Windows 7 (just as I have done with every single tex live version since 2012).

If I hard code the path and the names of the individual fonts included in the tex live fonts folder, everything works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec, lipsum}
    \setmainfont{libertinusserif-}[%
        Path = C:/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertinus/,
        Extension = .otf,
        UprightFont = *regular,
        BoldFont = *semibold,
        ItalicFont = *italic,
        BoldItalicFont = *semibolditalic]

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: works ok for me. But I have windows 10 and not a portable version. What happens if you run `fc-cache -fv`? Does it search the texmf-tree? And does it write a cache in `texmf-var\fonts\cache`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `'fc-cache' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Did you use the texlive command line? Is fc-cache in the bin folder?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If I run it inside the `\bin\win32\` folder, it spits out this:
C:/windows/fonts: caching, new cache contents: 1058 fonts, 0 dirs
C:/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype: skipping, no such directory
C:/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype: skipping, no such directory
C:/texlive2018/texmf-var/fonts/cache: cleaning cache directory
fc-cache: succeeded

Comment: Hm! Does this mean that it's a problem that I have renamed the `texlive` folder to `texlive2018`? I have done so with every previous version of texlive, and it hasn't been a problem before.

Comment: Don't run it inside \bin\win32. Check with the texlive command line.  https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#tlportable

Comment: Ok - I renamed `texlive2018` back to `texlive`, and now everything works. Interesting that this wasn't an issue with tex live 2017, which I also renamed `texlive2017` after installing it.

Comment: You could ask on the texlive list. But first you should really ensure that you are using the right command line with the path and the environment correctly setup. `fc-cache` and `pdflatex` should work.

Comment: > »Hm! Does this mean that it's a problem that I have renamed the texlive folder to texlive2018?« // Really, you should have mentioned that in your question. And what I don't understand: If you renamed it, why is the path in your examples `C:\texlive\...`, instead of `C:\texlive2018\...`?